# Truly Duplicates or Dr. Strangedupe?

Tags: discussion

#### Questions in Question

> **Unanswered**:
> [How to filter the edit comments admin page, show only current logged in author comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/31027/12615)
> <sup>*asked Oct 13 '11 at 19:57*</sup>
>
> **Possible Duplicate**:
> [Filtering the Admin Comments List to Show Only Comments from the Current User?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56652/12615)
> <sup>*asked Jun 27 at 8:40*</sup>

#### About Duplication

- [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)
  (Jeff Atwood at blog.stackoverflow.com)
- [Proposal for "Canonical Question and Answer" to address "Duplicate Post" issues](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/602/12615)
  (Meta WPSE)
- [A guide to moderating wordpress.stackexchange yourself - close voting](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1033/12615)
  (Meta WPSE)

#### The Issue

My first motivation to open this meta was the curiosity to know: case they were considered Dups, which one gets closed given their timing and status? And haven't found an answer in the previous docs.

But after reading the Strangedupe article, started to think that they may not be duplicates...
There's a slight difference in the Q's about comments made by *versus* made by **and** made to.

There's a secondary issue that, *before my edit*, Rutwick Gangurde answer to the "Possible Duplicate" had the code to answer the "Unanswered". But the code was not truly solving the Question, that the OP managed by himself as we see in the comments, hence my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options:

1. Leave as it is. If the best answer from one question doesn’t really answer the second question we have no real duplicate.
2. Close one as duplicate of the other. The time the question was asked is not the important point here. The question with lower quality and no answers should be closed.
3. Merge. Answers are combined under one question. Happens not often.

In this case … I think we have a duplicate. The author of the [first question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/31027/73) has probably just not thought of comments from the current user.

Comment: Yep, danke for the analytical eye and thoughtful conclusion. Glad to know of option 2 and of the rare occurrence of the 3rd. I'll follow up on the Q's later.